# Is it possible to create COM object with Haskell and use another COM object there?

Tags: haskell, com, f#, activator

For now I think that what I want is nonsense and no one knows anything about it...

But it will be good for production use if that could be possible so to be sure I ask question.

Example of what I want to have:

```ml
let A<'T> progid =
    Activator.CreateInstance
        ( Type.GetTypeFromProgID progid )
            :?> 'T

let cm = A<ISerialPort> "SerialPort.1"
let h  = A<IHaskell>    "Haskell.1"

let data = h.getData(cm)
```

I know there is http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hdirect but I can't even imagine how to use it... ( Not sure if it also should be updated for last haskell FFI )

Simple example of doing what I want will be perfect!

Comment: COM and Haskell can both interface with C code (or at least I think COM can, I don't use it much), but as far as I know they don't interface directly with each other. So you need to write something in C to link the two.